# Importing product image data from Hybris 5.2 to 6.7

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

Can you please let me know the best approach to migrate product image data in hybris .  Should this be done using impex or is there any other convenient approach?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://hybrismart.com/2017/01/10/best-practices-migrating-content-to-hybris/), you can find the approach to migrate your data. But you might struggle to implement it.

If you really not bother about URL changes after importing media/image then I would suggest using Hybris OOTB import/export wizard(System > Tools > Import / Export), where you can generate the export script for any ItemType and you can reImport generated Impex & media into the target system.

Like

```
# ---- Extension: core ---- Export Type: Media ----
"#% impex.setTargetFile( ""Media.csv"" );"
insert_update Media;&Item;@media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator];altText;catalog(id)[allownull=true];catalogVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true,allownull=true];code[unique=true,allownull=true];convertedMedias(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);dataPK;deniedPrincipals(uid);derivedMedias(&Item);description;internalURL;location;locationHash;mediaContainer(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),qualifier);mediaFormat(qualifier);metaData(&Item);metaDataDataPK;mime;original(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);originalDataPK;permittedPrincipals(uid);realFileName;removable[allownull=true];size;subFolderPath;supercategories(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code)
"#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch( ""SELECT {PK} FROM {Media!} WHERE {catalogVersion} IN (8796054355417)"");"
```

In above script, you can change the query to get only image media.

Also, there is one [advancedexport](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/~brendan.dobbs@hybris.com/Data+Exporter) extension available to serve the same purpose with some additional functionality.

---

You have to deal with Extract & Transform and Load phase on your own based on your business requirement.